# In Drupal Commerce - Rules configuration. What is the default operator in the conditions section?

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I'm setting up Drupal Commerce in the checkout Rules section. But this question also applies to any Rules.

Currently I have 3 conditions in my rule set. By default what is the default operator in this section? Is it an **OR** or **AND**? I see you can add these in manually, but it would be good to know what they are by default.

> Data comparison
>
> Entity exists by property
>
> Data comparison

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're confused as to how a specific rule is being evaluated by Drupal, you should enable the debug display for Rules. You can do so here: /admin/config/workflow/rules/settings

I find this helps a ton when trying to understand the eventual outcome of a Rule, and will show you an audit trail of how each condition was evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

AND

And here's some filler text to get me over the 30 character minimum.